# How can I display a "loading screen" while loading the main page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to make a loading screen.  While the main page is loading I want to display the loading image, and when the home page stops loading I want the loading image to disappear.

This is my `loading.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>loading</title>

    <!-- Include the heartcode canvasloader js file -->
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>


    <style type="text/css">
        body, html {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            overflow:hidden;
            background-color:#ffffff;
        }
        .wrapper {
            position:absolute;
            top:50%;
            left:50%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="canvasloader-container" class="wrapper"></div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var cl = new CanvasLoader('canvasloader-container');
        cl.setColor('#0c0d0c'); 
        cl.setDiameter(60); 
        cl.setDensity(65); 
        cl.setFPS(45); 
        cl.show(); 

        var loaderObj = document.getElementById("canvasLoader");
        loaderObj.style.position = "absolute";
        loaderObj.style["top"] = cl.getDiameter() * -0.5 + "px";
        loaderObj.style["left"] = cl.getDiameter() * -0.5 + "px";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my `mainpage.php`:

```
<?php

session_start();

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

?>


<html>
<head>
<title>
FUMC SCAN INVENTORY SYSTEM
</title>
</head>


       <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="fumc.png">


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/local.css" />

    <style>
            body{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                background-image: url("backimage.jpg");  
               }
            .title{
                width:1000px;
                height:144px;
                position:absolute;
                top:15px;
                left:100px;
                background:transparent url(una.png) no-repeat top left;
            }

            .home{
                width:50px;
                height:50px;
                position:absolute;
                top:60px;
                left:1030px;
                background:transparent url(home.png) no-repeat ;

            }

            .status{
                width:50px;
                height:50px;
                position:absolute;
                top:60px;
                left:1100px;
                background:transparent url(status.png) no-repeat ;

            }


            .putragis{
                width:-10px;
                height:100px;
                position:absolute;
                top:50px;
                left:1150px;
            }

            .about{
                width:1000px;
                height:400px;
                position:absolute;
                top:190px;
                left:150px;
                background:transparent url(about.png) no-repeat ;

            }

            .us{
                width:1000px;
                height:400px;
                position:absolute;
                top:530px;
                left:150px;
                background:transparent url(us.png) no-repeat ;

            }

            .rotate:hover
        {
            -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-30deg);
            -ms-transform: rotateZ(-30deg);
            transform: rotateZ(-30deg);
        }
        .grow:hover
        {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
            -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
            transform: scale(1.3);
                -webkit-transition:transform 0.5s ease;
        }
                .shrink:hover
        {
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
            -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
            transform: scale(0.8);
        }

        .capitalize {
    text-transform: uppercase;
                     }

    </style>

<body background="backimage.jpg">





    <div class="title" style="margin-left:50px;"><font style='margin-left:1158px;'><b><a  style='color:Transparent;'></a></b></font></div>

    <br><br><br> <br><br><br><br><br><br>


    <?php

    mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db('fumc');

    $sql = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM account WHERE username = '".$username."' ");

    while($data=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

        $fullname = $data['fullname'];

    ?>

    <font class="capitalize" style="color:green;margin-left:530px;"><b><i><?php echo $data['department'];?></i></b></font>        

    <?php } ?>


    <br><br>       

            <div style="border:10px solid RED;height:300px;margin-left:210px;width:850px;border-color:green;">
            <div style="border:2px solid RED;height:292px;;width:842px;border-color:white;margin-top:-6px;margin-left:-6px;">


                    <a href='it-request.php'><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt grow" style="margin-left:110px;color:green;font-size:100px;top:70px;"></div></a>  
                    <a href='inventory.php'><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase grow" style="margin-left:150px;color:green;font-size:100px;top:70px;"></div></a>  
                    <a href='login.php'><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-off grow" style="color:green;margin-left:150px;font-size:100px;top:70px;"></div></a>

                <br><br><br><br><br><br>


                    <font style='margin-left:130px;color:green;' ><b>REQUEST</b></font>
                    <font style='margin-left:173px;color:green;'><b>INVENTORY</b></font>        
                    <font style='margin-left:175px;color:green;'><b>LOG-OUT</b></font>    

    </div>            
    </div>

            <br><br><br>
            <center>
    <div  style='color:green;'>


        <?php   echo "Welcome ".$fullname.".!";    ?>

        <br><br>

    &copy; 2015-2016 Copyright University of Caloocan City. All Right Reserved.


    </div>    
            </center>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could display an iframe in the main page that links to the loading page.

```
<iframe src="loading.php" id='iframe'></iframe>
<!-- ^^ style iframe accordingly to center it or whatever -->
```

And add the following code to the main page:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('iframe').style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

This will display an iframe and only hide it when the document is fully loaded, though from your code in the main page it doesn't seem like it will take that long to load.

Comment: @V.Prince No problem. Remember to mark your question as answered by clicking on the tick next to my answer :)

Comment: The document.getElementById might not work on all browsers. Since you are using jQuery, I would change to: window.onload = function() {
 $("#iframe").remove(); } It would bring (slight) performance advantages too.

Comment: @fiprojects Why wouldn't `document.getElementById` work in all browsers? I'm quite sure jQuery selectors are done using the `document.getQuerySelector` function so it wouldn't make sense for the latter to have better performance...

Comment: @chris97ong *Whoops! You are right - I am wrong.* The different methods that can exist for referencing the DOM leads me to lean towards jQuery and avoid native javascript - my (incorrect) belief was the document.getElementByID may not be supported by either Mozilla or IE. I have since checked https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById and your solution is well supported/documented. My solution would still work (true?) though I was wrong to imply your proposed solution could prove problematic. Sorry about that.